# Sort data by newest to oldest PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, web

I have data stored on a database and I'm showing it on a webpage, at the moment it's ordering it from oldest to newest but I would like the newest to be shown first, I have tried a few things like adding this code that i found on another stack overflow question;

```
$files[$mod_time] = $basedir.'/'.$filename;
```

and tried doing a mysql query like this;

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $start, $per_page ORDER BY ID DESC");
```

maybe I'm not putting the code in the right place, here is the section of my code that's pulling the data;

```
if ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM memo Where uid = ? " ) ) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $uid2);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($id, $note, $uid3);
 }
        $output=array();
        $out_id=array();
        $out_note=array();
        $i=0;
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                //$out_id[$i]=$id;
                //echo $out_id[$i] . " / ";
                $out_note[$i]=$note;
               echo $out_note[$i]. " <br>";
               //echo $i. "<br>";
                $i++;    
            }
        $output = array($out_note,$out_id);
        rsort($output);
```

I'm new to PHP, any help or advice would be good for me, thanks a lot.

Here is what my tables look like;

[Heres the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epRRg.jpg)

Comment: What field in your `memo` table defines the time a memo was created?

Comment: Yes. Can you show the table definition? And describe that, maybe id in particluar.

Comment: I've added my table as a imgur link in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `uid` is an AUTO_INCREMENT field ?
If this is the case, you can simply replace this line :

`if ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM memo Where uid = ? " ) ) {`

by this one :

`if ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM memo Where uid = ? ORDER BY uid DESC" ) ) {`

Of course it would be better to have a column in your table that contain the date of the memo creation (e.g. DATETIME created_at). Then, you should use `ORDER BY created_at DESC`

You should read about the `ORDER BY` clause in MySQL :

http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/order_by.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, my uid is set as null at the moment, I'll try changing it to an auto increment, if that doesn't work I'll try adding a date created field and ordering it that way

Comment: Using this sort has worked for me if ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM memo Where uid = ? ORDER BY id DESC" ) ) {

Thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help. But you might consider using a 'created_at' field. Sometimes, you might face situations where last inserted ID is not supposed to be the last item chronologically (if you insert a record you forgot to add on the first place, for example).